# Java: Longest common subsequences

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a program for class where the goal is the return the longest common subsequence of two string inputs. For example, the LCS for "ALGORITHMS" and "DATA STRUCTURES" is "ARTS". The way I'm supposed to accomplish this is by filling a 2D array but I'm struggling with that part a bit. I'm not sure why the arrays do not match, and nested loops hurt my tiny brain.

For the code I have now I'm getting the error:

Ex.

"BAAB" and "ABBA"

Expected:

[ 0 1 1 1 ] [ 1 1 1 2 ] [ 1 1 1 2 ] [ 1 2 2 2 ]

My output:

[ 0 0 0 0 ] [ 0 0 1 1 ] [ 0 1 1 1 ] [ 0 1 1 1 ]

My code so far:

```
public LCSMatrix(String str1, String str2) {
    this.rowCount = (int) str1.length();
    this.columnCount = (int) str2.length();

    // Your code here
    matrix = new int[rowCount + 1][columnCount + 1];
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j <= columnCount; j++) {
          
          if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
             matrix[i][j] = 0;
          } else if (str1.charAt(i - 1) == str2.charAt(j - 1)) {
             matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
          } else {
             matrix[i][j] = Math.max(matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1]);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Once I correctly fill the array, I can then start on the method that uses the matrix to output a hashset of  the LCS's. Thanks!

Comment: I ran your code with some changes to make it runnable and it actually worked fine. You can remove the `this` keyword, declare your matrix type `int[][]`. The output I got is your expected output. You can check the code here: https://www.online-java.com/Z4jEMKvJUS